# plsql - oracle add_months adding additional day

Tags: oracle, plsql

**Oracle:** 12c

**Description:** Trying to add 99 years to a date using add_months, which works however it adds an additional day to the return date value. How should i properly add years to a date?

```
declare 
  toRetDate DATE;
  inputDate DATE;
  numYears number;
begin

  numYears := 99;
  inputDate := TO_DATE('28-FEB-85', 'DD-Mon-YY' );
  toRetDate := add_months(inputDate, numYears*12);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(toRetDate);
end;
```

Output:29-FEB-84

Comment: As explained in my Answer, ADD_MONTHS does not randomly "add a day" to the result. With that explanation: do you really need the result to be 28 February 84? If so, why? Why isn't 29 February OK?

Comment: I'm looking to explicitly add years but retain the same day. As per my question which stipulates adding years only to a date. The exception to this case of course would be Feb 29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this way:

```
declare 
  toRetDate DATE;
  inputDate DATE;
  numYears number;
begin

  numYears := 99;
  inputDate := TO_DATE('28-FEB-1985', 'DD-Mon-YYYY' );
  toRetDate := inputDate + INTERVAL '99' YEAR; --add_months(inputDate, numYears*12);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(to_date(toRetDate,'dd-mon-yyyy'));
end;
```

Although it's worth noting that the arithmetics with intervals is limited (if not broken) because it simply "increments" the month/year value of the date value. That can lead to invalid dates (e.g. from January to February).

**EDIT:**
In General `Add_months` generally adds `30/31`(depending on months) to the date on which its applied. The case is slight different for monthends. If `add_months` is done for month of `FEBRUARY`, it will add (28/29) days depending its a `leap year` or not.
If your requirement is to simple add `99 years` without checking if the resultant date is a valiad or not, then you can use `INTERVAL`, but if you really wanted to check if the resultant date should be very well evaluted and correct date then you must your `ADD_MONTHS`. It does not make any sense to first use `INTERVAL` then check if the resultant date(using any logic) is a valid date or not. Oracle has already provided solution for such scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

ADD_MONTHS does not add a day to the result. Rather, it has this very general feature: if you ADD MONTHS to a date, and that date is the end of the month in that particular month/year, then the result of ADD_MONTHS is the last day of the resulting month.

So, for example, if you add one month to January 31, you always get February 28 (or Feb 29 in a leap year). If you add one month to June 30, you get July 31.

If you add a month to February 28, you get March 31 UNLESS it's in a leap year; in a leap year Feb 28 is not the last day of the month, so if you add a month to it you get March 28.

In all cases, if the result is a day number greater than the number of days in the resulting month, the result is simply the last day of that month.

**EDIT**: In a comment below this Answer, the OP asks if there is a way to keep the exact same day of the month, with the exception of Feb. 29 (which should become Feb. 28 in a non-leap year).

The answer is YES. As @Xing shows in the other answer, adding `interval '99' year` will preserve the date, but it may cause trouble when the input date is Feb. 29 and the resulting year is not a leap year. That can be fixed with a preliminary check. It can be done with an IF statement or with a CASE expression. I prefer the latter because it works the same in PL/SQL and in SQL; there is no IF in plain SQL.

```
toretdate := case when to_char(inputdate, 'mm-dd') = '02-29'
                  then (inputdate + 1) + interval '99' year - 1
                  else inputdate + interval '99' year end
```

The trick is, when the `inputdate` is 29 February, push it forward one day to make it March 1, then add 99 years (still March 1), and then subtract one day to make it either February 29 (if it's a leap year) or February 28 (otherwise).

Comment: Is there a better way to add time to have it stick to the same exact day? In my case the 28th? I have read about the interval feature how it can lead to invalid dates. However I was thinking since I only want to add years, it should suffice in order to keep the same exact day but only add years. Unless it's the 29th of Feburary. The only exception.